# How to get a href no to wrap

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to get the a href tag verbiage to not wrap to the next line as seen in the image below

[image]

```css
.badge-example-outline {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #cbd1d6;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 24px;
  margin: 0.1rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}

.ao-text-header {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: CharlesModern-Medium, CharlesModern-Regular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="sdps-is-relative badge-example-outline sdps-p-around_medium sdps-m- 
       around_medium">
  <sdps-badge sdps-id="spdb-promotional-beta-overlay" type="promotional" status-text="Beta" promotional-type="beta" sr-label-prefix="You have got" sr-label-suffix="notifications" is-overlay>
  </sdps-badge>
  <div class="ao-text-header">Account Overview has a new look</div>
  You can view your retirement accounts below, or <a [href]="_globalConstants.links.classicAO">go back to the classic experience.</a>
</div>
```

I added white-space: nowrap; in the stylesheet for the a class but this is not working

Comment: @Justinas — The missing `.` was preventing the question from demonstrating the problem. Adding it doesn't solve the *problem*, it fixes the *question* so it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @HereticMonkey — It makes the code in the question match the rendering issue expressed in the picture in the question. My edit to the code in the question *clearly* matches the OP's intentions.

Comment: @Quentin So OP should be fixing his code, not you!

Comment: @Justinas — Why? The intention was clear. The error (again, in the construction of the question, not the the problem they are asking about) was a trivial typo. Why leave the question in a state where the problem was non-reproducible when the question is so easily fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added white-space: nowrap; in the stylesheet for the a class but this is not working

That won't help: The text isn't wrapping *inside* the `<a>` element.

Text wrapping is what happens when a text reaches the end of a line and breaks to start a new one. That isn't what is happening here.

You made `.badge-example-outline` a flex column so **every element** (or text node) is arranged in a column.

If you want two elements to be kept together instead of being split into separate boxes in the column then you need to wrap them in a container such as a `<div>`.

```css
.badge-example-outline {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #cbd1d6;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 24px;
  margin: 0.1rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}

.ao-text-header {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: CharlesModern-Medium, CharlesModern-Regular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="sdps-is-relative badge-example-outline sdps-p-around_medium sdps-m- 
       around_medium">
  <sdps-badge sdps-id="spdb-promotional-beta-overlay" type="promotional" status-text="Beta" promotional-type="beta" sr-label-prefix="You have got" sr-label-suffix="notifications" is-overlay>
  </sdps-badge>
  <div class="ao-text-header">Account Overview has a new look</div>
  <div>
  
  You can view your retirement accounts below, or <a [href]="_globalConstants.links.classicAO">go back to the classic experience.</a>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, don't apply `display: flex` to the parent element in the first place.